# Q: How do I space elements evenly?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 elements In spans (idk if span is better than div for this) that I want to show on the same line spaced out evenly.

Thanks in advance!!

```css
.icons span{
   justify-content: center;
    margin: 20px 50px; 
    float: left;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 2px;
    
}
```

```html
 <div class="icons">
            <span>
                <h1>Honest</h1>
            </span>
            <span>
                <h1>Accurate</h1>
            </span>
            <span>
                <h1>Reasonable</h1>
            </span>
```

Comment: `.icons { display: flex; justify-content: space-between; }` or maybe `justify-content: space-around` - here's a reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather do it using unordered list, use text-align center, display: inline-block and use padding on list to make even space in between.

```css
.row{
text-align: center;
}
ul{
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
}
li{
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;
padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row icons">
    <ul>
        <li><h1>text1</h1></li>
        <li><h1>text2</h1></li>
        <li><h1>text3</h1></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: flex;` and `justify-content: space-between;` to your `.icons` class.  In `.icons span`, remove your left/right margin value.

```css
.icons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.icons span{
    margin: 20px 0px; 
    float: left;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 2px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="icons">
  <span>
    <h1>Honest</h1>
  </span>
  <span>
    <h1>Accurate</h1>
  </span>
  <span>
    <h1>Reasonable</h1>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox

```
    .icons {
        display: flex;
    }
    .icons span{
       justify-content: center;
        margin: auto; 
        float: left;
        border-color: black;
        border-width: 2px;

    }

    <div class="icons">
        <span>
            <h1>Honest</h1>
        </span>
        <span>
            <h1>Accurate</h1>
        </span>
        <span>
            <h1>Reasonable</h1>
        </span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without flex, the easiest dirty way is by simply using width percentages on inline-blocks:

```
.icons {
  text-align:center;
}

.icons span{
  display:inline-block;
  width:32%;
}
```